# why coroutines 1st run on caller thread but after first suspension point it runs on DefaultExecutor in “Dispatchers.Unconfined”?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

Below code prints

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.*

    fun main() = runBlocking<Unit> {
        launch(Dispatchers.Unconfined) {
            // not confined -- will work with main thread
            println("thread ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
            delay(500)
            println("thread ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
        }
    }
```

1st run on caller thread but after first suspension point it runs on DefaultExecutor in “Dispatchers.Unconfined”

```
 thread main
 thread kotlinx.coroutines.DefaultExecutor
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the description of [`Dispatchers.Unconfined`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-dispatchers/-unconfined.html), it explains exactly this behavior:

> A coroutine dispatcher that is not confined to any specific thread. It executes initial continuation of the coroutine immediately in the current call-frame and lets the coroutine resume in whatever thread that is used by the corresponding suspending function, without mandating any specific threading policy. **Note: use with extreme caution, not for general code**.

Answer (score 2):

The `Unconfined` dispatcher has no thread associated with it. In almost all circumstances the coroutine resumes on the thread where the users calls `continuation.resume()`.

In the specific case you're showing, you call the standard function `delay` so Kotlin must internally handle both its suspension and resumption. To make this happen, it maintains a scheduled thread pool to which it submits the resumption task, scheduled with the delay you specify.

The `Unconfined` dispatcher is useful only in specialized scenarios, where you write your own infrastructure and want to be in control of the thread where the coroutine resumes. Basically, it short-circuits the entire dispatcher mechanism.